# Loading Android onto Beaglebone Black

Tags: android, beagleboneblack

I tried loading Andrew Henderson's Android [image](http://icculus.org/~hendersa/android/) onto my Beaglebone Black (Rev B) using online [instructions](http://elinux.org/Beagleboard%3aAndroid), but am not having any luck.  I copied the image onto an SD card using the Win32DiskImager, loaded it into the slot, connected the HDMI to a monitor, held down the boot button, and powered on the board.  I see constant LED activity, but hours have gone by and I have yet to see an Android boot up screen.  Any help getting this working is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the video configuration was incompatible with my computer monitor.  I removed the video section from the uEnv.txt file and connected to a TV instead of a computer monitor - after that I was able to see Android boot up.  Thanks to Andrew and his quick response:

> Well, the image is set up to use an uEnv.txt file in the boot
>   partition that is recognized by the bootloader in the BBB's eMMC
>   storage.  You don't need to hold down the boot button to boot from the
>   microSD card.  If there is a problem with how the image was written to
>   the microSD card, though, holding the boot button will force the boot
>   to the non-working microSD image (so it will just hang there).
>
> The first thing to check is to make sure that the image has been
>   downloaded correctly.  The md5sum of the image is:
>
> c2fd49a7297ee5318e470d9376a0393f  BBB_JB_Android_3_8_13.img.bz2
>
> Next, make sure the image is decompressed.  The uncompressed image is
>   something like 4GB in size (the size of the original microSD card it
>   came from).  If you download the image and then write it as-is (via
>   DiskImager or dd or what have you) without decompressing it first, it
>   won't boot.
>
> But, I suspect that the trouble is in the uEnv.txt file.  If you are
>   using a monitor as your display, it probably doesn't support the
>   resolution that the image is designed for.  There is a hard-coded
>   "video=720x480-16@60"  kernel command line option in there that forces
>   the resolution to a CEA video mode (audio/video over the HDMI
>   connection).  If you are using a computer monitor, rather than an HDMI
>   TV, that mode is most likely not supported.  You can change that
>   resolution to 640x480, 800x600, etc. to force a particular mode.  Or,
>   you can remove the "video=..." option entirely to go to the highest
>   resolution supported by the display.  If your display can't accurately
>   report EDID (resolution) information to the BBB, I believe that kernel
>   that I am using defaults to 1024x768.  You won't get audio in a
>   non-CEA mode, though.